# Travelling to the US from Dubai/UK while having US passport and Indonesian passport

Tags: transit, international-travel, dual-nationality

I am planning to go to the US from the UK or Dubai soon. I have Indonesian passport and US passport. I want to go to the US with my US passport and live and work there. Does anyone know how to do it? I do not want lose my Indonesian passport. And I might be staying in the US for kind of a long time. And how does it work for the flight ticket? I entered UK using my indonesian passport and want to go to the US for living and work. Should i go to dubai first then fly out to The US?  Please anyone have any experience like this? Thank you.

Comment: Are the names on both passports the same?

Comment: Yes both passport is under my name

Comment: The US allows dual nationality. So no problem there. Indonesia, however, restricts it. So if you want to keep both passports, make sure the Indonesian authorities don't learn about your US citizenship. https://www.nnuimmigration.com/dual-citizenship-usa/